# sql server 2008 express, how login as admin

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sql-server-2008, authentication

I am pretty newbie on sqlserver.
I just want to logon by Management Studio on a sqlserver just for backup a db.
But it seems that I haven't enough permissions because I am guest.
Anyone could explain me how to logon as admin ?
I am local and domain admin and the sqlserver 2008 was been installed just for a wsus server.
Thank you.

Comment: I assume that you are logged-in as administrator, but SSMS keeps telling you that you do not have all the required permission. Did you try to right-click the SSMS icon and choose "Run as administator"?

Comment: "Run as administrator" doesn't do anything for actually logging into SQL.  It just elevates the SSMS process client side.  The authentication token sent to SQL Server is the same.

Comment: hopefully it was as easy as doing a run as admin, but if not and you are now responible for the db and you don't know the pw and or account that was given access you'll need to bring the service up in single user mode to correct this issue.

Comment: @squillman actually, if you put `Domain Admins` or the local `Administators` group into the SQL Server admins during installation, then Run As Administrator will, indeed do something. UAC will strip either of those memberships out of the logged in user's token. Running as administrator will run SSMS with that token in place, allowing a login where it was denied before. Of course, this is why you don't use those groups in that field, but that's another story :)

Comment: The WSUS setup is a restricted SQL express setup...I'm sure there's documentation on *how* it's set up someplace.

Comment: @MDMarra - Excellent point.  I never ever use those groups so I just pass it off as an assumption anymore...  Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @Luigi - You didn't give us nearly enough information. Are you trying to log into the default instance or a named instance? Are you trying to use Windows authentication or SQL authentication? Is the authentication method you're trying to use enabled? Are you connecting from the SQL Express computer itself or from a remote computer? If remote, what network protocols do you have enabled?

Comment: @joeqwerty it's the wsus instance. I am trying to use windows authentication. I dont know if the authentication method is enabled. Yes I am connecting from sql express in localhost server.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, a default install of WSUS will install a named instance of SQL as such: ServerName\MICROSOFT##SSEE. If that's the case then you need to provide the instance name when connecting with SSMS.

Comment: @joeqwerty I tried to connect to **ServerName\MICROSOFT##SSEE** but it does not find the server. If I connect to **ServerName\SQLEXPRESS** it works but I can't access to the wsus db __SUSDB__ ... I have the same problem if I want install a new db instance by installing the kaspersky security center (that is an admin kit to control all antivirus client). The same when I have to access by backup exec to backup the db.

Answer (score 4):

When you install SQL Server, there was a screen where you select a user or group to be administrators on that SQL Server instance. You must log in with an account that was granted that permission. Being a local admin on a server does not give you permission to MS SQL Server unless that group is explicitly added.